# VBA To Execute Alter Table Statement

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to execute an `Alter Table` statement through VBA.  I use the function [Allen Brown Table Info()](http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html) to get the field type, and this VBA to actually run the SQL Sytnax.  Here is my issue:

> 1) `Debug.Print fld.Name` prints the correct field naem
>   2) `Debug.Print SecondSQL` prints valid & correct SQL Syntax (if I run in a query it actaully alters the table)

What should I alter in order for the VBA syntax to alter the table?

```
Function AlterTable()
Dim secondSQL As String
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("___TestTable")
For Each fld In rs2.Fields
If fld.Name <> "ID" Then
    If FieldTypeName(fld) <> "Text" Then
        Debug.Print fld.Name            
        secondSQL = "ALTER TABLE ___TestTable ALTER COLUMN [" & fld.Name & "] TEXT(40);"
        Debug.Print secondSQL
        DoCmd.RunSQL secondSQL
    End If
End If
Next

'Disposing of Objects
Set fld = Nothing
rs2.Close

End Function


Function FieldTypeName(fld As DAO.Field) As String
'Purpose: Converts the numeric results of DAO Field.Type to text.
Dim strReturn As String    'Name to return

Select Case CLng(fld.Type) 'fld.Type is Integer, but constants are Long.
    Case dbBoolean: strReturn = "Yes/No"            ' 1
    Case dbByte: strReturn = "Byte"                 ' 2
    Case dbInteger: strReturn = "Integer"           ' 3
    Case dbLong                                     ' 4
        If (fld.Attributes And dbAutoIncrField) = 0& Then
            strReturn = "Long Integer"
        Else
            strReturn = "AutoNumber"
        End If
    Case dbCurrency: strReturn = "Currency"         ' 5
    Case dbSingle: strReturn = "Single"             ' 6
    Case dbDouble: strReturn = "Double"             ' 7
    Case dbDate: strReturn = "Date/Time"            ' 8
    Case dbBinary: strReturn = "Binary"             ' 9 (no interface)
    Case dbText                                     '10
        If (fld.Attributes And dbFixedField) = 0& Then
            strReturn = "Text"
        Else
            strReturn = "Text (fixed width)"        '(no interface)
        End If
    Case dbLongBinary: strReturn = "OLE Object"     '11
    Case dbMemo                                     '12
        If (fld.Attributes And dbHyperlinkField) = 0& Then
            strReturn = "Memo"
        Else
            strReturn = "Hyperlink"
        End If
    Case dbGUID: strReturn = "GUID"                 '15

    'Attached tables only: cannot create these in JET.
    Case dbBigInt: strReturn = "Big Integer"        '16
    Case dbVarBinary: strReturn = "VarBinary"       '17
    Case dbChar: strReturn = "Char"                 '18
    Case dbNumeric: strReturn = "Numeric"           '19
    Case dbDecimal: strReturn = "Decimal"           '20
    Case dbFloat: strReturn = "Float"               '21
    Case dbTime: strReturn = "Time"                 '22
    Case dbTimeStamp: strReturn = "Time Stamp"      '23

    'Constants for complex types don't work prior to Access 2007 and later.
    Case 101&: strReturn = "Attachment"         'dbAttachment
    Case 102&: strReturn = "Complex Byte"       'dbComplexByte
    Case 103&: strReturn = "Complex Integer"    'dbComplexInteger
    Case 104&: strReturn = "Complex Long"       'dbComplexLong
    Case 105&: strReturn = "Complex Single"     'dbComplexSingle
    Case 106&: strReturn = "Complex Double"     'dbComplexDouble
    Case 107&: strReturn = "Complex GUID"       'dbComplexGUID
    Case 108&: strReturn = "Complex Decimal"    'dbComplexDecimal
    Case 109&: strReturn = "Complex Text"       'dbComplexText
    Case Else: strReturn = "Field type " & fld.Type & " unknown"
End Select

FieldTypeName = strReturn
End Function
```

Comment: It's possible that it won't execute because it's open, you may have to write the changes to an array and then run them all after you close rs2.  You should try looking at the Execute method, it allows better error handling.  The difference between the two, with examples, is [explained nicely on this Wiki site](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/RunSQL_vs_Execute).

Comment: Are you saying the `DoCmd.RunSQL` does not run? If it failed, an error would raise.

Comment: @Parfait - when stepping through the code the line is hit, no error is thrown.  When the code completes, if I design view the table "___TestTable" there are multiple fields that are data type other than Text

Comment: @JohnnyBones - that is a good theory!  I am looking into syntax of populating an array to iterate after closing rs2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like @Johnny Bones was correct with his statement of the syntax not executing due to it being open.  I altered syntax and use this which works exactly as it should.  May not be the best syntax, and def needs some error handling, but it is working now!

```
Function Blue()
Dim CreateTableSQL As String
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Set db = CurrentDb()

CreateTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE [GreenSocks] (FieldPK COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY, fieldname TEXT);"
db.Execute CreateTableSQL

Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("___TestTable")
For Each fld In rs2.Fields
    If fld.Name <> "ID" And fld.Name <> "Store Number" Then
        If FieldTypeName(fld) <> "Text" Then
            Debug.Print fld.Name

                strSQL = "INSERT INTO GreenSocks (fieldname) VALUES ('" & fld.Name & "' );"
                DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

        End If
    End If
Next

Set fld = Nothing
rs2.Close

strSQL = "select fieldname from GreenSocks"

Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
For Each fld In rs3.Fields

    Debug.Print fld.Value

    secondSQL = "ALTER TABLE __TestTable ALTER COLUMN [" & fld.Value & "] TEXT(40);"

    DoCmd.RunSQL secondSQL

 Next

  Set fld = Nothing
  rs3.Close

End Function
```